# Unable to install mysq on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to install mysql on ubuntu using following command.

sudo apt-get install mysq-server.

Then, tried run following command. But, no luck

sudo apt-get update

The above commands are tried with corporate netwrok(office). But, when tried with wifi(through mobile hotspot), it is working fine.

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to type "l" in "mysql"?

Comment: The error messages you're getting are probably more descriptive than just "no luck".  Why do you keep them a secret? :p

Comment: And remember, that you can always run `apt search <program>` to get a list of installable software from the apt repository. In your case it would be `apt search mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, in corporate offices they might block you from installing softwares using firewall. contact your network administrator for help in installing by getting proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing a typo you are typing **mysq** instead of **mysql**..
use following command
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Hope this helps.